# How do I link cells interactively with jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How would I be able to link cells to create a new cell so that I call add a global value like in the snippet. In the snippet there are 3 chosen rows that can be chosen at random by the user and any number of them.

What I want to do is be able to link the chosen rows to add a new cel that has an overall value captured by the user.

How do I link the cells depending on which ones the user chooses. with jquery in a interactive way as to not reload the page.

I want to know how to go about to solve this problem.

the code snippet only shows a visual example after the rows are chosen by the user which should create a new cel next to it.

they have to be linked as to those 3 have a global value of the new cell...

[image: added cell]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('tbody tr').eq(0).find('td').eq(7).css('background-color', 'green');
  $('tbody tr').eq(3).find('td').eq(7).css('background-color', 'green');
  $('tbody tr').eq(4).find('td').eq(7).css('background-color', 'green');
});
```

```css
table,
td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
td {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: Your requirement is totally unclear. Also, why should we bother with PHP code if you need a JavaScript UI?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan that is my table, I posted it as to show that I am doing this to php code.

Comment: Don't. Keep the code as minimal as possible but with a [mcve]. Clarify your needs cause I cannot understand where, on what action etc you want to create that mystical new cell...

Comment: Even after your edit it's **not clear** how the user chooses the cells (there's no JS function in your code that does this) - What you mean by *`be able to link the chosen rows to add a new cel that has an overall value captured by the user`* and what do you mean by *`How do I link the cells depending on which ones the user chooses. with jquery in a interactive way as to not reload the page`*. please explain exactly what you're after and **what's the expected result**.

Comment: Also *`should create a new cel next to it.`* ...next to what?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I added more to try to explain better

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want a function like this:

```
$('tr').click(function(){
  // The tr that was clicked
  var $tr = $(this);

  // Create a new td with a green background-color
  var $newTd = $('<td></td>').css('background-color', 'green');

  // Append the new td to the clicked row
  $tr.append($newTd);

  // Add an empty td to all other rows
  $('tr').not($tr).append('<td></td>');
});
```